# ScaleType on ImageButton results in tiny image

Tags: android, layout

Hey I have a grid of `ImageButton`s that is being scaled by display width and contains a **PNG** file as image. I add the whole thing to the linear layout like this:

```
public void createButtons(){

            int buttonX = 9;
            int buttonY = 9;
            int size    = 80;
            int tag     = 0;

          TableLayout layout = new TableLayout (this);
          layout.setLayoutParams( new TableLayout.LayoutParams(900,900) );
          layout.setPadding(1,1,1,1);
          layout.setBackgroundColor(0xff00af00); //green

          RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel);
          ll.addView(layout);

          for(int x=0;x<buttonX;x++)    {

              TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);                     
              for(int y=0;y<buttonY;y++)    {
                but[x][y] = new ImageButton(this); 
                but[x][y].setBackgroundColor(0xff0000af); //blue
                but[x][y].setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonmask3); 
                     but[x][y].setScaleType(ImageButton.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE); 
                tr.addView(but[x][y], height/10,height/10);
                }
                layout.addView(tr);
            }
}
```

The problem is, that the layout now looks like the following:

[image: does]

whereas it is supposed to look like:

[image: should]

(this one was a quick photoshop but you get the idea, that the scale is supposed to fill the button completely)

What can I do about these tiny images? I tried **CENTER_INSIDE**, **FITXY** and all the other **ScaleTypes** but I haven't been lucky so far :/

The `width` is taken from the screen width (or height in landscape)

the buttonmask3.png is about **170*170 px**.

Comment: Are you sure you should be adding with both parameters based on height tr.addView(but[x][y], height/10,height/10);

Comment: FIT_XY would do it, it's gotta be something with the views width and height

Comment: Well, the whole design is supposed to be display-independent. It should look on a Galaxy Ace exactly as on a Tab 10. I don't think the way I set the size can be a problem.

Comment: I just inserted int values instead of width/10 + I set FIT_XY. FIT_XY Made them even smaller 0o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is  the padding that the `ImageButton` comes with naturally.

adding

```
but[x][y].setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

along with

```
but[x][y].setScaleType(ImageButton.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Solved it for me.